# how can I convert string to binary data using .net

Tags: .net, visual-c++, managed-c++

How can I convert a string variable to a binary data variable using .net 1.1?

I found a way of doing this:

```
ASCIIEncoding^ ascii = gcnew ASCIIEncoding;
String^ unicodeString = L"This Unicode String* contains two characters with codes outside the ASCII code range, Pi (\u03a0) and Sigma (\u03a3).";
array<Byte>^ binaryData = ascii->GetBytes( unicodeString );
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What kind of "binary data"? A PNG picture? An integer representing the sum of the ASCII characters in the string?

Comment: i have a string that I want to convert to base64. I need a byte array in order to use Convert::ToBase64String

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664345/string-to-binary-in-c-sharp (3rd hit on google)

Comment: You do realize that is C# right?

Comment: @user1064036: Doesn't matter; the core .Net classes are usable from all CLI languages.

Comment: @MSalters: Please don't add tags you aren't familiar with.  This is a .NET 1.1 question, not a C++/CLI question.

Comment: @BenVoigt: It was originally tagged C++ (as in ISO C++), which was entirely inappropriate.

Comment: @MSalters: And removing the `c++` tag was the right thing to do.  But adding the `c++-cli` tag was no different than the `c++` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .NET 1.1, you only have access to the broken Managed Extensions for C++ compiler.  It is broken, you should not use it.

However, IIRC, the syntax would be something like:

```
System::Byte bytes __gc[] = Encoding::ASCII::GetBytes(inputString);
System::String __gc* base64string = Convert::ToBase64String(bytes);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
byte[] InputbyteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(inputString);
string B64String = Convert.ToBase64String(InputbyteArray)
```

Comment: you say you "found" a solution - an hours after I answered, what is the difference between my answer and your solution?

Comment: Your "solution" isn't in the requested language.

Comment: I disagree, it was a .net question not a c++ or clr specific question. The solution is .net, just different syntax - which lets be honest is a trivial conversion.

Comment: Finding someone who knows Managed Extensions for C++ is non-trivial.