# How to get information of a Byte in a binary format

Tags: c#

I want to have my results in this part of code in a binary format rather than in a hexadecimal!!! How can I do it?????

```
  string temp = Byte Format.To Hex(result.Data, "", "");
```

I mean I want to see my results in (0011010...) rather than being converted to a hexadecimal number.

Thanks for you answers in advance.

Comment: What data type is `result.Data`?

Comment: Have you checked this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664345/string-to-binary-in-c-sharp

Comment: `string result = Convert.ToString(myByte, 2).PadLeft(8, '0');`

Comment: this is the type of Data        public byte[] Data { get; }

Answer (score 0):

`Convert.ToString()` should do the job. [See Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.tostring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Convert_ToString_System_Int32_System_Int32_)

If you have a single byte it will cast to an `int`

`Convert.ToString((int)yourByte, 2);` will convert it to base 2 (binary).

Comment: They did not work for me!!

Comment: Here is a demo of it working https://dotnetfiddle.net/UBJRsn

Answer (score 0):

```
string temp = Convert.ToString(bytes, "X");  //X means hexadecimal
```

Comment: It did not work for me as well