# How do I make it so every binary code has a (') before it and a (',) after it? ex. '01011011',

Tags: c#

I need help from [String to Binary in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664345/string-to-binary-in-c-sharp).
I have tried to make it like `'01100100',` but it comes out like `01100100',` without the apostrophe on the left side. In my code it says pad left(8, '0') and I can't seem to get it like (1, " ' ") or something.

```cs
private void Button2_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    richTextbox1.Text = ToBinary(ConvertToByteArray(richTextbox1.Text, Encoding.ASCII));
}
public static byte[] ConvertToByteArray(string str, Encoding encoding)
{
    return encoding.GetBytes(str);    
}

public static String ToBinary(Byte[] data)
{
    return string.Join("', ", data.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8,'0')));   
}
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're inserting `',` between the strings in `ToBinary`, but you're not adding the quote before or at the end. `PadLeft` is being applied beforehand—all it is doing is making sure every number is 8 digits long by adding zeros to the left end.

Comment: Im new to coding that kinda hurts my brain but i think i know what you're saying a bit. So, you're saying i can apply it after hand ?

Comment: What is input and what output you are expecting? show us relative code instead of full functionality. `Convert.ToString(byt, 2)` will be compile time error

Comment: i am trying to put a `script` into a textbox then it would obfuscate or turn in to `Binary` code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use this?

```
return "'" + data.Select(byt => Convert.ToString(byt, 2).PadLeft(8,'0') + "',";
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you just need to add the leading (and trailing) quotes outside of the call to `Join`. I don't know C#, so I can't tell you how to do that, but string concatenation is a common operation, so it should be easy enough to find.